# Audio bitrate sense for byte array

Tags: java, arrays, audio, bitrate

I use mp3spi to read audio files and then convert them to byte array

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream baout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);

byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int c;

while ((c = sound.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
    baout.write(buffer, 0, c);

    break; // i read only first 4096 bytes, to make my other stuff faster     
}

sound.close();
baout.close();
byte[] data = baout.toByteArray();
```

If i read audio with following data

```
frame rate: 38.28125
frame length: -1
frame size: -1
sample rate: 44100.0
channels: 2
bitrate: 320000
```

i receive an array with over 3900 zero values

```java
int countZero = 0;
for(byte b: data){
    if(b == 0){
        countZero++;
    }
}
System.out.println("count zero values " + countZero); // 3900 - 4000
```

What is the sense of this zero values?
Some traks have 85 instead 0.

Is the difference between different bitrate in this equal values?
Is there a way to count, how many this values follow each other, by knowing the bitrate?

Comment: It is probably just silence. Music files often start and/or finish with a period of silence.

Comment: in many files there are 2% of zero values. May be is it realy silence. thanks